# WatchService uses 100% of CPU on CentOS

Tags: java, centos, cpu-usage, watchservice

I am using a `WatchService` in my application. When I run my application on a `Windows` environment, the application uses less than 1% of the `CPU`. When the same application is run on my `Linux` server, it uses 100% of the `CPU`. When the `WatchService` thread is disabled, the `CPU` is back to normal.

I am using `CentOS 5.9` with `OpenJDK-1.7.0_x86_64`.

Here is the thread:

```
private static void startDirectoryWatcher() {
    if (thWatcherM == null) {
        thWatcherM = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mediaMode == MediaMode.Directory && !exit) {

                    File music = new File(path);

                    WatchService watcherM = null;

                    watcherM = music.toPath().getFileSystem().newWatchService();
                    music.toPath().register(watcherM, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

                    while (!exit) {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                        if (watcherM != null) {
                            WatchKey watchKey = watcherM.take();

                            List<WatchEvent<?>> events = watchKey
                                    .pollEvents();
                            for (WatchEvent<?> event : events) {
                                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                                    System.out.println(event.context().toString());
                                }
                            }

                            if (!watchKey.reset()) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (watcherM != null) {
                        watcherM.close();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        thWatcherM.setName("Dir-Watcher-M");
        thWatcherM.start();
    }
}
```

Why is it using **100%** of the `CPU`?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? You could start by removing pieces of code one by one until the CPU usage no longer happens, this will then allow you to see which particular function is causing the issue.

Comment: Do you have `inotifywait` installed on the server?

Comment: what part of your code consumes the most CPU resources? have you used profiler for your code?  if you don't, then consider Netbeans profiler. It is a good tool for such purposes.

Comment: This code can't be the one you're actually using - what else did you omit?

Comment: What is watchKey.pollEvents() doing? This sounds ominously.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this in Debian, using Oracle Java 1.7.0_60-b19.  I realize this isn't a solution, but is SELinux active, and if so, have you tried disabling it to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Could `watcherM` be null? That would cause what you are seeing.

Comment: Lex: I'll do that now. laune: I only omitted the printStackTrace() and try blocks, however when I comment out the call to this function, CPU usage is normal. This is the code that causes the 100% usage. [pollEvents()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html#pollEvents()) Thomas: No. Java doesn't use it though, right? Rafael: I'm writing the code on a Windows machine and deploying it on a CentOS. Profiling on the Windows shows everything normal. OldCurmudgeon: The Thread.sleep(50) would prevent 100% usage in this case. I'll test it anyway.

Comment: I'm running multiple variations of the software. I'm going to run them for a bit then I'll post the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04.

sudo apt-get install inotify-tools dropped my resource usage considerably.  Not sure what/if inotify-hookable also helps, but it comes with a lot more dependencies, so maybe hold off on that unless inotify-tools is not enough.

Thx to comment by @Thomas Jungblut for this solution.